# Scraping a website with javascript commands (Jsoup)

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping

I want to scrape a website but it has javascript commands that create elements that I want to get into my program.
How can I execute the javascript commands on this website and than scrape it after it has the new elements?
I am using Jsoup library for scraping and java ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

You can find many examples, e.g. http://www.frontendtest.org/blog/selenium-webdriver-example-java/

Comment: I tried selenium but I dont know how to get the HTML code of the website after I executed the js commands.

Comment: @Elsar, its easy - elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: Actually I can't even use the FirefoxDriver..  I am trying to use `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` but I get the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;`